# Find the value of $a$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find $a$ for which $f(x) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\right)x^5-3x+\ln5 \;$ decreases for all $x$ with $a\neq 1$ and $a\geq -4$.

My try:

For $f(x)$ to decrease
$$5x^4\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\right) -3 <0\implies x^4\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\right) < 3/5 $$

How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds true for every $x$ only if $$\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\le 0$$or $${\sqrt{a+4}\over 1-a}\le 1$$Surely $a>1$ is one region of answer. For $a<1$ we have $$\sqrt {a+4}\le 1-a\to a+4\le a^2-2a+1\to a^2-3a-3\ge 0\to\\a\ge {3+\sqrt {21}\over 2}\\a\le {3-\sqrt {21}\over 2}$$therefore the region of the answer is $$[-4, {3-\sqrt {21}\over 2}]\cup (1,\infty)$$

Comment: Why the coefficent of $x^4$ need to be negative.

Comment: If it is positive then for large enough $x$ the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: Oh yes , thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.......

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have

$$f(x) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\right)x^5-3x+\ln5 \implies f'(x) = 5\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\right)x^4-3\le 0$$

then we need

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\right)x^4- \frac35 \le 0 $$

that is true for all $x$ when

$$\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} -1\le0 \iff \frac{\sqrt{a+4}+a-1}{1-a}\le0$$

Comment: oh no, @gimusi, fix it...

Comment: Ummm... $f(x)$ *decreases*...

Comment: Opsss...I was dealing with the incresing case! I fix, thanks